# useEffect break array of useState at first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am learning react hooks. I am having mock data js call "MockFireBase.js" as below:

```
const userIngredientsList = [];
export const Get = () => {
    return userIngredientsList;
}
export const Post = (ingredient) => {
    ingredient.id = userIngredientsList.length + 1;
    userIngredientsList.push(ingredient);
    return ingredient;
}
```

Then my react hooks component "Ingredients.js" will call this mock utilities as following details:

```
const Ingredients = () => {
  const [userIngredients, setUserIngredients] = useState([]);
  
  // only load one time
  useEffect(() => { setUserIngredients(Get()); }, []);
  
  const addIngredienHandler = ingredient => {
    let responsData = Post(ingredient);
    setUserIngredients(preIngredients => {
      return [...preIngredients, responsData]
    });
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <IngredientForm onAddIngredient={addIngredienHandler} />
      <section>
        <IngredientList ingredients={userIngredients} />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
  )
}
```

When I added first ingredient, it added two (of course I get same key issue in console.log). Then I added second ingredient is fine.

If I remove the useEffect code as below, it will work good.

```
// only load one time
useEffect(() => { setUserIngredients(loadedIngredients); }, []);
```

I am wondering what I did anything wrong above, if I use useEffect

Comment: The variable `userIngredientsList` will be passed as a reference. So in the `addIngredienHandler` the `Post()` function adds it directly to the original variable `userIngredientsList` and the `setState` parameter `preIngredients` is still using the original reference (which had the item added via post). The use effect should spread the array `setUserIngredients([...Get()])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in useEffect. It's about mutating a global `userIngredientsList` array.

1. from useEffect you set initial component state to be `userIngredientsList`.
2. Then inside `addIngredienHandler` you call `Post()`. This function does two things:
   2a. pushes the new ingredient to the global `userIngredientsList` array`. Since it's the same instance as you saved in your state in step 1, your state now contains this ingredient already.
   2a. Returns this ingredient
3. Then, `addIngredienHandler` adds this ingredient to the state again - so you end up having it in the state twice.

**Fix 1**
Remove `userIngredientsList.push(ingredient);` line from your `Post` function.

**Fix 2**
Or, if you need this global list of ingredients for further usage, you should make sure you don't store it in your component state directly, and instead create a shallow copy in your state:

```
useEffect(() => { setUserIngredients([...Get()]); }, []);
```